# How to change a HTML template while developing a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Suppose I am using the following template to make a popup plugin using jQuery. The following code is inside a jQuery plugin file in the default options.

```html
<div class="popup">
    <div class="title"></div>
<div>
```

So, I want to change `title` based upon arguments passed by user.

```
$('#test').pop_up({
    'title': 'this title i want to use'
});
```

**Full Code**

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        pop_up: function(options) {

            //Settings list and the default values
            var defaults = {
                template: '<div class="popup"><div class="title"></div></div>',
                title: 'Hello',
                content: 'Are you sure to continue?'
            };
            
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            $(this).each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                  $(options.template).find('.title').html(options.title); //here 
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: r u using only `jquery.js` in your `HTML` ? or give me ur library names used  for the page

Comment: Please add the code of your plugin to the question.

Comment: Kindly check i have add code

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="http://vast-eng.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup();
    });
  </script>
```

try this js for easy popups find More [Click here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay/)

Comment: actually i want to develop my plugin